# Upper Numbering of Ramification Groups of Absolute Galois Groups for Totally Ramified Extensions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

Suppose $K'/K$ is a totally ramified extension of $p$-adic fields of degree $e.$ A [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07708v1.pdf) (p.9, line 15) I am reading seems to use the following formula for the upper numbering on the absolute galois groups $$G_{K'}^{eu}=G_{K}^{u}$$ for $u>0.$

They quote Proposition 15, Chapter IV of Serre's Local Fields for this fact, which says that the Herbrand function $\varphi_{F/L}$ and its inverse $\psi_{F/L}$ satisfy transitivity formulas $$\varphi_{F/L}=\varphi_{L'/L}\circ \varphi_{F/L'}\text{ and }\psi_{F/L}=\psi_{F/L'}\circ\psi_{L'/F}$$ for an extension of fields $F/ L' / L.$

How does the formula above follow from this proposition? Or is the formula not true in general (quite possibly I am missing some subtlety that is making this formula work in the paper)?

Comment: Transitivity always holds.

Comment: On looking at that paper, I got the impression that the smaller field $K$ might not have been just any old $p$-adic field. Were there any conditions on $K$ that applied in this part of the paper?

Comment: $K$ is an unramified finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$

Comment: Aha. I finally looked at the paper again. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension $K'\supset K$ is *tamely* ramified in the paper you’re reading. But in the case of tame ramification, everything is concentrated at the origin of the Herbrand graph. That is, $\varphi^{K'}_K(x)=x/e$ for $x\ge0$. All follows from that.

Comment: Thank you, Lubin! That clears up why I was finding it difficult to prove this for general totally ramified extensions. Because of your answer I also found this good reference (https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/ibf/book/vol.pdf) which treats this question carefully in III.3.